# Got errors when using Curl to call the LPS API

Tags: php, curl

I am pretty new to here and desperately looking for help to resolve some issues with the using Curl to call the LPS API

Here is the code we been using

```
$xml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:gen="http://www.auspost.com.au/Schema/ProductandServiceFulfilment/LodgementManagement/generateLabel:v1">
<soap:Header />
<soap:Body>
    <gen:get>
        <Generate>
            <InterfaceHeader>
                <InterfaceName>generateLabel</InterfaceName>
                <InterfaceVersion>1.0</InterfaceVersion>
                <MessageType>Request</MessageType>
                <BusinessReferenceID>12121212</BusinessReferenceID>
                <SourceSystemID>Merchant</SourceSystemID>
                <Timestamp>2013-05-08T12:45:12</Timestamp>
            </InterfaceHeader>
            <ServiceHeader>
                <RequestType>PDF</RequestType>
                <RequesterId>12345</RequesterId>
                <LabelMessage>test</LabelMessage>
            </ServiceHeader>
            <LabelGroup>
                <Layout>A4-1pp</Layout>
                <Branding>true</Branding>
                <LeftOffset>12</LeftOffset>
                <TopOffset>12</TopOffset>
                <Label>
                    <TemplateName>EPARCEL</TemplateName>
                    <InternationalPrintList>LABEL</InternationalPrintList>
                    <ArticleId>3NZ12000001601000600206</ArticleId>
                    <Barcode/>
                    <Source>12345</Source>
                    <OrderRef>34567567</OrderRef>
                    <ConsignmentId>1000310</ConsignmentId>
                    <ArticleCount>1</ArticleCount>
                    <TotalArticles>1</TotalArticles>
                    <Product>12345</Product>
                    <DeliverySignatureCapture>True</DeliverySignatureCapture>
                    <PickupSignatureCapture>True</PickupSignatureCapture>
                    <!-- Zero or more repetitions:  -->
                    <PostagePaidIndicator>true</PostagePaidIndicator>
                    <ParcelCharacteristics>
                        <DeliveryInstructions>DELIVER 5 PM - 7 PM. IF PREMISES UNATTENDED, LEAVE IN A SECURE LOCATION OUT OF THE WEATHER.</DeliveryInstructions>
                        <PickupInstructions>pick</PickupInstructions>
                        <DangerousGoodsIndicator>true</DangerousGoodsIndicator>
                        <HeavyGoodIndicator>true</HeavyGoodIndicator>
                        <Fragile>false</Fragile>
                        <Contents>
                            <ContentQuantity>12</ContentQuantity>
                            <ContentWeight>21.22</ContentWeight>
                            <ContentUnitValue>12.22</ContentUnitValue>
                            <TotalContentValue>1222.22</TotalContentValue>
                        </Contents>
                        <TotalConsignmentValue>1212</TotalConsignmentValue>
                        <ExportClearanceNumber>12344</ExportClearanceNumber>
                        <Height>5655</Height>
                        <Length>234</Length>
                        <Width>123</Width>
                        <Weight>10</Weight>
                    </ParcelCharacteristics>
                    <RecipientAddress>
                        <Name>Greg E Burns</Name>
                        <AddressLine>111 Bourke St</AddressLine>
                        <Suburb>Melbourne</Suburb>
                        <State>VIC</State>
                        <Postcode>3000</Postcode>
                        <CountryCode>AU</CountryCode>
                        <Phone>0397654321</Phone>
                    </RecipientAddress>
                    <SenderAddress>
                        <Name>Greg E Burns</Name>
                        <AddressLine>111 Bourke St</AddressLine>
                        <Suburb>Melbourne</Suburb>
                        <State>VIC</State>
                        <Postcode>3000</Postcode>
                        <CountryCode>AU</CountryCode>
                        <Phone>0397654321</Phone>
                    </SenderAddress>
                </Label>
            </LabelGroup>
        </Generate>
    </gen:get>
</soap:Body>
```

';

```
    $url = 'https://webapi.auspost.com.au/soap/LodgementManagement_MerchantTest_v1';

    $ch = curl_init();      
    $header[] = "Content-Type: application/soap+xml"; 
    $header[] = "charset=UTF-8"; 
    $header[] = "Accept:application/xml"; 
    $header[] = "action=\"generateLabel\""; 
    $timeout = 300;       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    //no ssl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'lps_merchant_testing:LPSprodtesting@1');        //user,password
    $xmls = curl_exec($ch);      
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        print curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);      
    print_r($xmls);
```

and if we use the Linux platform it is fine with no error, however, when switching to PHP got the issue as

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I fixed your code markdown, it requires 4 spaces at the start of the line.  You are expecting other to put some effort in to help you.  So, you need to out the effort in to make it easier for them.  There is no point to the image, please copy the 6 word error message into your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the cURL LPS SOAP request from PHP using exec().  I also notice that you are missing the soap envelope and quote from the end of your $xml line:

```
...
</soap:Envelope>';
```

Running with exec():

```
$start = time();
$filename  = "tmp_label_".$start.".xml";
$handle = file_put_contents($filename, $xml);

$credentials = "lps_merchant_testing:LPSprodtesting@1";
$url = "https://webapi.auspost.com.au/soap/LodgementManagement_MerchantTest_v1";
$header = '"Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=\"generateLabel\""';

exec("curl -v -X POST -d@$filename $url --header $header --insecure --user $credentials", $response);
unlink($filename);

print_r($response);
```

Seems to do the job!